# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

**System information**
- Windows 10
- TensorFlow backend (yes / no):  yes
- TensorFlow version:  1.14.0
- Keras version:  2.24
- Python version:  3.6
- CUDA/cuDNN version:  10
- GPU model and memory:  gtx 1050 ti

**Describe the current behavior**
I installed tensoflow and keras via conda. Then i tried to run this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mean_squared_error")

x = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=500)

print(model.predict([10]))`
```

When i run this code I get the error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Workspace/tensorflow/hello_world_of_nn.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

When i try this:
`python -c 'import keras as k; print(k.__version__)'`

I get the error:

```
C:\Users\xxx>python -c 'import keras as k; print(k.__version__)'
  File "<string>", line 1
    'import
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mean_squared_error")

x = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=500)

print(model.predict([10]))
```

Please note the usage of `keras.models.Sequential` and `keras.layers.Dense`.